# Model I-V in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, numerical-integration

Model I-V.

Method:
Perform an integral, as a function of E, which outputs Current for each Voltage value used. This is repeated for an array of v_values. The equation can be found below.

[image]

Although the limits in this equation range from `-inf` to `inf`, the limits must be restricted so that (E+eV)^2-\Delta^2>0 and E^2-\Delta^2>0, to avoid poles. (\Delta_1 = \Delta_2). Therefore there are currently two integrals, with limits from `-inf` to `-gap-e*v`  and `gap` to `inf`.

However, I keep returning a `math range error` although I believe I have excluded the troublesome E values by using the limits stated above. Pastie of errors: http://pastie.org/private/o3ugxtxai8zbktyxtxuvg

Apologies for the vagueness of this question. But, can anybody see obvious mistakes or code misuse?

My attempt:

```
from scipy import integrate
from numpy import *
import scipy as sp
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import math

e = 1.60217646*10**(-19)
r = 3000
gap = 400*10**(-6)*e
g = (gap)**2
t = 0.02
k = 1.3806503*10**(-23)
kt = k*t

v_values = np.arange(0,0.001,0.0001)

I=[]
for v in v_values:
    val, err = integrate.quad(lambda E:(1/(e*r))*(abs(E)/np.sqrt(abs(E**2-g)))*(abs(E+e*v)/(np.sqrt(abs((E+e*v)**2-g))))*((1/(1+math.exp((E+e*v)/kt)))-(1/(1+math.exp(E/k*t)))),-inf,(-gap-e*v)*0.9)
    I.append(val)
I = array(I)

I2=[]
for v in v_values:
    val2, err = integrate.quad(lambda E:(1/(e*r))*(abs(E)/np.sqrt(abs(E**2-g)))*(abs(E+e*v)/(np.sqrt(abs((E+e*v)**2-g))))*((1/(1+math.exp((E+e*v)/kt)))-(1/(1+math.exp(E/k*t)))),gap*0.9,inf)
    I2.append(val2)
I2 = array(I2)

I[np.isnan(I)] = 0
I[np.isnan(I2)] = 0

pl.plot(v_values,I,'-b',v_values,I2,'-b')
pl.show()
```

Comment: If you have poles on the axis, don't you really want to be doing this integral with complex analysis?  Computing the residues is much easier.

Comment: Rescale your variables so *numerical computation* does not involve really small floats such as `k` and `e`, etc. It's all fine when doing pure math, but numerical algorithms often do not work well when the floats are so small.

Comment: You are missing braces in the denominator of the argument to `exp` in the second Boltzmann term or you have simply forgotten to replace `k*t` there with `kt`. Besides, you are integrating in `[0.9*gap-ev, 0.9*gap]`. Perhaps you'd like to split it into two integrals: one in `(-inf,-0.9*gap-ev]` and one in `[0.9*gap, inf)`.

Comment: Besides, there are no `abs`'s in the denominators of the first two terms of the integrand. Having them there hides the wrong integration range.

Comment: Stylistic tips to make your code easier to read and debug: (1) Split long lines into multiple shorter lines; (2) Use `def` not `lambda` unless the function is extremely simple; (3) Split complicated formulas into multiple steps (e.g. define f(E) as a separate function). :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem in the end was to use a heaviside function to prevent`E` variable from exceeding `\Delta` variable.

Answer (score 4):

This question is better suited for the [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site. Still here are some points for you to think about.

First, the range of integration is the intersection of `(-oo, -eV-gap) U (-eV+gap, +oo)` and `(-oo, -gap) U (gap, +oo)`. There are two possible cases:

- if `eV < 2*gap` then the allowed energy values are in `(-oo, -eV-gap) U (gap, +oo)`;
- if `eV > 2*gap` then the allowed energy values are in `(-oo, -eV-gap) U (-eV+gap, -gap) U (gap, +oo)`.

Second, you are working in a very low temperature region. With `t` equal to 0.02 K, the denominator in the Boltzmann factor is 1.7 µeV, while the energy gap is 400 µeV. In this case the value of the exponent is huge for positive energies and it soon goes off the limits of the double precision floating point numbers, used by Python. As this is the *minimum* possible positive energy, things would not get any better at higher energies. With negative energies the value would always be very close to zero. Note that at this temperature, the Fermi-Dirac distribution has a very sharp edge and resembles a reflected theta function. At `E = gap` you would have `exp(E/kT)` of approximately 6.24E+100. You would run out of range when `E/kT > 709.78` or `E > 3.06*gap`.

Yet it makes no sense to go to such energies since at that temperature the difference between the two Fermi functions very quickly becomes zero outside the `[-eV, 0]` interval which falls entirely inside the gap for the given temperature when `V < (2*gap)/e` (0.8 mV). That's why one would expect that the current would be very close to zero when the bias voltage is less than 0.8 mV. When it is more than 0.8 mV, then the main value of the integral would come from the integrand in `(-eV+gap, -gap)`, although some non-zero value would come from the region near the singularity at `E = gap` and some from the region near the singularity at `E = -eV-gap`. *You should not avoid* the singularities in the DoS, otherwise you would not get the expected discontinuities (vertical lines) in the I(V) curve (image taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:STJ_IV_Curve.jpg)):

[image: STJ current-voltage diagram]

Rather, you have to derive equivalent approximate expressions in the vicinity of each singularity and integrate them instead.

As you can see, there are many special cases for the value of the integrand and you have to take them all into account when computing numerically. If you don't want to do that, you should probably turn to some other mathematical package like Maple or Mathematica. These have much more sophisticated numerical integration routines and might be able to directly handle your formula.

Note that this is not an attempt to answer your question but rather a very long comment that would not fit in any comment field.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the math range error is that your exponential goes to infinity. Taking `v = 0.0009` and `E = 5.18e-23`, the expression `exp((E + e*v) / kt)` (I corrected the typo pointed out by Hristo Liev in your Python expression) is `exp(709.984..)` which is beyond the range you can represent with double precision numbers (up to ca. 1E308).

Two additional notes:

- As noted by others, you should probably rescale your equation by using a unit system which delivers numbers in a smaller range. Maybe, atomic units are a possible choice as it would set `e = 1`, but I did not try to convert your equation into it. (Probably, your timestep would then become quite large, as in atomic units the time unit is about is 1/40 fs).
- Usually, one uses the exponential notation for float point numbers: `e = 1.60217E-19` instead of `e = 1.60217*10**(-19)`.

Comment: `(E+e*v)/kt` is dimensionless (energy divided by energy) and its value would be the same regardless of the choice of units. This is also true for the whole integrand as the other two expressions are also dimensionless. The only proper solution to the problem is to split the integration range into intervals and to derive for each interval a proper approximate expression (e.g. using Taylor series) that would not lead to over-/underflow.

Comment: That's true of course. I was more referring to the prefactors like charge of the electrons in SI units, which one could get rid of. But I agree, that won't solve the problem with the exponential function.